# programatically create subscribers

Tags: ros, data, subscribe, logging

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I am trying to make a simple logger that given a list of topics via a service or an action, subscribes to and logs the data from these topics. This requires me to initiate subscribers on the fly and the callback data handlers are proving not easy to get around. Any ideas?

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/60925/programatically-create-subscribers/) by [makokal](https://answers.ros.org/users/31/makokal/) on ROS Answers with karma: 1295 on 2013-04-17

Post score: 1

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [joq](https://answers.ros.org/users/25/joq/) on 2013-04-17**:
Have you looked at rosbag?

**Comment by [makokal](https://answers.ros.org/users/31/makokal/) on 2013-04-21**:
Yes, but what we need goes beyond rosbag, we need to be able to process the data independent of ROS

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I'm doing a similar thing at the moment. So far, it only seems possible in rospy, not roscpp. I'm using the services:

```
rosapi/topics
rosapi/topic_type
```

to get a full list of topics and msg types, then a little (lots) of dodgy string manipulation getting the correct format of topic  to use with:

```
__import__(pkg,globals(),locals(),[topictype],-1)
```

(this dynamically creates a `from pkg import topictype` C++ doesn't seem to have an equivalent)

once you have the topic name and type, it's easy to subscribe to it. You can filter the full list by comparing against your provided list to only subscribe to topics you are interested in.

---

Originally posted by [Chengarda](https://answers.ros.org/users/9541/chengarda/) with karma: 156 on 2013-12-12

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [McMurdo](https://answers.ros.org/users/1973/mcmurdo/) on 2014-05-31**:
_type_name = **import**('std_msgs.msg', globals(), locals(), ['String'], -1)

and then

rospy.Subscriber("/some_topic", _type_name.String, callback)

works for me. However is there a way to eliminate having to type String? I want to invoke the above import and be able to use _type_name directly.